# Porting Android to BB: When clicking the "Info" button, the app crashes

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, porting, blackberry-10

Recently we ported successfully an Android application on BlackBerry 10.

Everything worked fine, except the thing that when clicking the "Info" button from the action bar that appears at the bottom of the screen - the application crashes.

I suppose that button should display an About, or Help page. We do have in our application a such page (as an ActionItem in the ActionBar).

Does anyone know if there is a way we can fix this, so that when clicking the "Info" button to display our About page? Or at least to do something to prevent the app from crashing, for example hide that button.

Thank you.

Comment: iirc the bb10 phones are emulating android 2.3, which doesn't have the action bar. I would guess that is the root of your issue. Maybe if you implement it the old menu button way it won't crash? Just a guess though, I have no experience with the new bb stuff. Note: [This Page](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/mastertopic_2016760_11.html) confirms that the android runtime is 2.3.3 on Blackberry 10

Comment: We use SherlockActionBar, so we support an Action Bar for lower level devices. But you might be correct in your assumption, good starting point for investigation. Thank you @FoamyGuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on BB developer forums, and got a pretty good answer:

> This is actually a known issue in the current Android Runtime on the
>   BlackBerry 10 simulator release. It has nothing to do with your
>   application, as this action bar is part of the Android Runtime and not
>   your application. Normally when you section the "Info" button you
>   would see a screen showing you have to use the back swipe gesture used
>   in Android Runtime applications. If you wanted your own About button, you would have to create your own menu.

Comment: Maybe add a link to the original source?

Comment: @Andy : Andy, man. Is it possible to sue the sherlock action bar stuff and still build my android app using google API's 2.3.3? My app is crashing in the BB10 sim and I don't know why, so I'm trying to explicitly build my app for 2.3.3 API's... but sherlock uses API's level 15. How do I set my app to build for level 10, and the sherlock code at level 15, i get build errors etc

Comment: The SherlockActionBar should not cause any problems, as it is designed to run on lower versions of Android. We have an app that uses SAB and successfully ported it on BlackBerry. Make sure the `minSdkVersion` in `AndroidManifest` file points to a lower version, for example 8.